# SQL query with check in another table

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

- `TOOLS  ( id | name | qt)`, which is a list of all equipment
- `TOOLSOUT ( idtools | qt )`, which is a list of all the equipment that are beyond

I want to show all equipment with the quantities available.

If the `TOOLS.id` is not present in `TOOLSOUT.idtools` print qt normally. If the `TOOLS.id` is present in TOOLSOUT.idtools print (TOOLS.qt - TOOLS.qt)

How can I write this query?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you show us what you have tried to solve the issue?

Comment: Check your question. Seems you meant: `print (TOOLS.qt - TOOLSOUT.qt) `

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query. Seems that's what you're looking for.

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN t2.idtools IS NULL 
        THEN t.qt 
        ELSE t.qt - t2.qt 
    END AS qt
FROM
TOOLS t
LEFT JOIN TOOLSOUT t2 ON t.id = t2.idtools
```